# How to display retrieved data from external API call to wordpress front-end page?

Tags: elementor, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using Elementor Pro form. on submission I'm trying to achieve the below:

1. Post to external API
2. Redirect to thank you page.
3. Retrieve a token from the API
4. on thank you page; a button is there when clicked; open
   external link with the token generated from step 2 like this:
   [https://example.com/login?token={{token-from-step-2}}](https://example.com/login?token=%7B%7Btoken-from-step-2%7D%7D)

I managed to get point 1 to work.

How to get the rest to work?